# WP 3.3 my rich text category editor toolbar is gone!

Tags: tinymce, editor

Up until today's update, the code below has worked flawlessly to add a rich text editor control to the category description editor. Today it stopped working after updating to 3.3

Any clues what to tweak here?

```
<?php 
function my_editor_init()
{
    if ( is_admin() || defined('DOING_AJAX') ) 
        {
        if ( current_user_can('manage_categories') )remove_filter('pre_term_description', 'wp_filter_kses');
        }
}

add_action('load-categories.php', 'my_admin_init');

add_action('load-edit-tags.php', 'my_admin_init');

function my_admin_init() 
{
    if ( user_can_richedit() && isset($_GET['action']) && 'edit' === $_GET['action'] && ( !empty($_GET['cat_ID']) || ( !empty($_GET['taxonomy']) && !empty($_GET['tag_ID']) ) ) ) 
    {
        add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'my_mceinit');
        add_action('admin_footer', 'wp_tiny_mce');
        add_action('admin_head', 'my_head');
    }
}

function my_mceinit($init) 
{
    $init['mode'] = 'exact';
    $init['editor_selector'] = 'description';
    $init['elements'] = 'category_description,description';
    $init['plugins'] = 'safari,inlinepopups,spellchecker,paste,fullscreen';
    $init['theme_advanced_buttons1'] .= ',image';
    $init['theme_advanced_buttons2'] .= ',code';
    $init['onpageload'] = '';
    $init['save_callback'] = '';
    return $init;
}

function my_head() 
{ ?>
<style type="text/css">#category_description_tbl,#description_tbl{border:1px solid #dfdfdf;}.wp_themeSkin .mceStatusbar{border-color:#dddddd;}</style><?php 
} 

add_action('init', 'my_editor_init');

?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This changed in 3.3

Add this line below your my_head() function....

```
wp_enqueue_style('editor-buttons');
```

[image: that didnt work. any other suggestions?]